# Hash Insert in MySql ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I had a below hash in ruby form submission and i want to insert these values in to answers table any trick will be appreciable. thanks in advance.

```
"ans"=>{"0"=>"Chocolates", "1"=>"Jerries", "2"=>"Nuts", "3"=>"Apples", "4"=>"Mangoes","5"=>"Poemgrante"}
```

i want to insert like below

```
insert into answers(answer)values("Choclates")    
insert into answers(answer)values("Jerries")
insert into answers(answer)values("Nuts")
insert into answers(answer)values("Apples")
insert into answers(answer)values("Mangoes")
insert into answers(answer)values("Poemgrante")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you have hash like below:

```
params = {"ans"=>{"0"=>"Chocolates", "1"=>"Jerries", "2"=>"Nuts", "3"=>"Apples", "4"=>"Mangoes","5"=>"Poemgrante"}}
```

so you can do like

```
params["ans"].each_value do |value|
  Answer.create(answer: value)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
params = {"ans"=>{"0"=>"Chocolates", "1"=>"Jerries", "2"=>"Nuts", "3"=>"Apples", "4"=>"Mangoes","5"=>"Poemgrante"}}

params["ans"].values.each { |ans| Answer.create(answer: ans) }
```